# How to set a fixed width of editor window in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, settings, installation

Recently I have got a new 22" monitor. Finally it's possible to keep all needed windows in Eclipse open while having the main editor window wide enough to display all 120 columns. Problem now is when I wide up or narrow down windows on the left or right side of the editor. Editor's width narrows down or wides up. I'd like to set its width fixed to some value and let the other windows 'breathe' in width.

Take a look at the [illustration](http://twitpic.com/rt9td/full).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use **[detached views](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-21a.htm)**, that way your main editor is not affected by the other windows resize operations.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/detachview2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Either that, or use fast views, which minimises the views down to an icon that can be conveniently popped up when you need to use them. This is especially handy for things like the JUnit test view, as suggested by the JUnit Eclipse documentation

http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-junit.htm